# opengl platform bounces

Tags: c++

recently I started a project on OpenGL in C++ and I kind of hit a snag. The player is a cube measured at 32x32 and the platforms at 32x32. When gravity comes in to place, the player falls as they should, it hits the platform, and continuously bounces up and down.

Anyways, here's my C++ code:

Player.h:

```
typedef void *(*ccallbackv)(void);
typedef void *(*ccallbackc)(const std::string);

const float g_gravity = 0.52f;

class Player :
    public CBaseObject
{
    // Variables
    int m_health, m_stealth, m_maxHealth, m_maxStamina;
    float jumpForce;
    bool mEnabled;
    ccallbackv* c_damageCallback;
    ccallbackc* c_killedCallback;
    bool m_isOnGround;

    // Movement Variables
    Vector2f velocity;
    BoundingBox2D<float>* m_tilePosition, *m_oldTilePosition;
    GLuint m_texture;
    Level* level;



public:
    Player(void);
    virtual ~Player(void);
    virtual void SetDamageCallbackFunc(ccallbackv* func) { this->c_damageCallback = func; }
    virtual void SetKilledCallbackFunc(ccallbackc* func) { this->c_killedCallback = func; }
    virtual void Kill(CBaseObject* killer = NULL);
    virtual void Reset();
    virtual void Tick();
    virtual void Render();
    virtual void KeyPress(char);
    virtual void Enabled(bool v) { this->mEnabled = v; }
    virtual bool isEnabled() { return this->mEnabled; }
    virtual void Collision();
    virtual bool OnGround(bool r) { if(r != m_isOnGround) { m_isOnGround = r; } return m_isOnGround; }

    virtual void SetLevel(Level* level) { this->level = level; }
    virtual Level* GetLevel() { return level; }

    virtual Vector2f* getPosition(){
        return &this->m_tilePosition->getVector();
    }
    virtual BoundingBox2D<float>* getBoundries() { return this->m_tilePosition; }

    virtual void setPosition(const Vector2f position){
        return this->m_tilePosition->setVector(position);
    }
    virtual bool IsAlive(){
        return m_health > 0;
    }
    virtual bool HasStamina(){
        return m_stealth > 0;
    }
    virtual void SetJumpForce(float force){ this->jumpForce = force; } 
    virtual float getJumpForce() { return this->jumpForce; } 
};
```

Player.cpp:

```
int movement_position = 0;
float old_y = 0;

Player::Player(void)
{
    this->SetTypeString("PLAYER_NON_NPC");
    m_texture = ImportTexture("Player.png");

    this->velocity = Vector2f(0,0);
    this->m_tilePosition = new BoundingBox2D<float>(64,0,32,32);
    this->mEnabled = true;
    this->OnGround(false);
    old_y = -5;

}

Player::~Player(void)
{
}
void Player::Kill(CBaseObject* killer){
    if( this->c_killedCallback != NULL )
        (*this->c_killedCallback)( std::string( "Player was killed by entity " + ( !killer->GetTypeString().empty() ) ? killer->GetTypeString()
        : "unknown."));

    this->m_health = 0;

}
void Player::Reset(){
    this->m_health = 100;
    this->m_stealth = 100;
}
void Player::Tick()
{
    if(!this->mEnabled) return;
    float ticks = std::toFloat(Time::getSystemTicksSeconds());

    m_oldTilePosition = this->m_tilePosition;

    if( GLOBALS::pressedKey == 'd' ){
        velocity.setX(clamp<float>(velocity.getX() + (1.0f / 10000) * ticks, -0.05f, 0.05f));
    }
    else if( GLOBALS::pressedKey == 'a' ){
        velocity.setX(clamp<float>(velocity.getX() - (1.0f / 10000) * ticks, -0.05f, 0.05f));
    }
    else {
        velocity.setX(0);
    }

    this->Collision();


    if( !m_isOnGround OR ( old_y != this->getBoundries()->getY() ) ){
        velocity.addY(clamp<float>(0.0001f * ticks, -0.005f, 0.005f));
    }


    if(m_oldTilePosition != this->m_tilePosition)
        glutPostRedisplay();


    if( ( old_y == this->getBoundries()->getY() ) ) {
        this->m_tilePosition->setY(old_y);
        velocity.setY(0);
    }
    this->m_tilePosition->addVector(this->velocity);
}

void Player::KeyPress(char i){

}
void Player::Collision(){
    if( this->level == NULL ) return;

    float old_yc = 0;

    std::vector<Tile*> mapData = this->level->GetMap();

    OnGround(false);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < mapData.size(); ++i){
        BoundingBox2D<float>* source = this->getBoundries();
        BoundingBox2D<float>* mapTile = mapData.at(i)->getBoundries();
        Vector2f mapTileVector = mapTile->getIntersectionDepth(source);
        Vector2f abs = mapTileVector.Absolute();

        if( mapTileVector != Vector2f(0,0) && mapTile->IntersectsWith(source)){

            if( abs.getX() > abs.getY() ){
                if( old_y <= mapTile->top() )
                    OnGround(true);

                if(m_isOnGround){
                    this->getBoundries()->setVector(Vector2f(this->m_tilePosition->getX(), this->m_tilePosition->getY() + mapTileVector.getY()));
                    old_yc = this->getBoundries()->getVector().getY();
                }
            }
        }   
    }

    old_y = old_yc;
}

void Player::Render()
{
    if( this->m_texture == 0x0 ) return;

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->m_texture);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        ::glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); ::glVertex2f(this->m_tilePosition->getX(),this->m_tilePosition->getY());
        ::glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); ::glVertex2f(this->m_tilePosition->getX(),this->m_tilePosition->getY() + this->m_tilePosition->getH());
        ::glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); ::glVertex2f(this->m_tilePosition->getX() + this->m_tilePosition->getW(),this->m_tilePosition->getY() + this->m_tilePosition->getH());
        ::glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); ::glVertex2f(this->m_tilePosition->getX() + this->m_tilePosition->getW(),this->m_tilePosition->getY());
        glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

}
```

Comment: You have to look at how physics works: implement friction, and lossy collisions... And I'd also implement a "gating logic", that would prevent "wiggling", if the motion is too small...

Comment: What's the expected behavior?

Comment: Just to sit on top of the platform, without falling through it jerking. Although, my math skills aren't all that great so advanced physics may become a problem.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't Time::getSystemTicksSeconds() returning ticks since program startup, or similar, which would make the velocity greater and greater until eventually the collision test misses?  Ticks needs to be the difference between current and previous time step.

Comment: Yes but your function isn't being called once a second.  At 0.1s it's 1/10, but at 10s it's 1 * 10, i.e. the calculated velocity is increasing with time even though the block isn't moving.  Eventually the velocity will be enough that the collision check fails. That's why you need to use delta time, rather than actual time.

Comment: Is there any particular way that I can create the delta time from the system time(Or some other way) and make velocity work the way it's suppose too? I am unable to find this information.

Comment: It's simple really.  If your object moves P units on X in 1 second, then in N seconds it will move P * N units.  In your case N is the difference between the current time and the last time the function was called.  Remember, you're updating the state at each tick, rather than trying to calculate the state after N ticks (where a tick is an interval of time).

Comment: Well I managed to make a delta time by doing some research and the object itself is moving a lot slower. But the issue still exists even when velocity is increasing the amount it's suppose too.